# Tortoise SVN: Show all changesets in branch that haven't been merged to trunk?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, branch

we started working with development- and featurebranches and it is actually quite useful. But, as we do most of the bug fixes in development branches it often happens, that I work on several things at a time, waiting for them to be reviewed by our QA. Now I fear that I will forget to merge a changeset/revision back into trunk after I get clearance and so a bugfix actually doesn't find its way into trunk.

Is there a way to show the changesets from one branch that haven't been merged back to another branch (trunk) yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right-click on your working copy of the trunk
- Choose "merge" from the TSVN context menu
- in the merge wizard, chose "range of revision"
- for the url, enter the url of your branch
- click the "show log" button
- in the log dialog, check the checkbox "include merged revisions".

Now, that log dialog (started from the merge dialog) will show you all revisions that have already been merged from the branch into trunk in gray and with an additional icon.
All revisions that are shown black were not merged yet from the branch into trunk.

Comment: Okay, "retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported" hints that we use a stone age SVN version around here. Will get it updated and try again.

Comment: Update done, works perfectly. "Include merged revisions" even isn't necessary, as it only shows the revisions that were merged in this commit - and as this is my dev branch there are no merges into it that are relevant to merge down.

Comment: This answer might have been before this feature, but as @DevJohn states below, there is also a checkbox next to "include merged revisions" called "Hide non-mergeable revisions" that is probably more useful. This checkbox will hide all previously merged revisions, leaving you just with what hasn't been merged.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic approach is to use

```
svn log --verbose
```

on your feature as well as your development branch. If necessary you can limit
the query to specified revision:

```
svn log --verbose -r r1:r2
```

The following [link](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/faq/svnchangesets.html) about svn changesets might be interesting for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Stefan's answer. There is now a checkbox on the log dialog called [ ] Hide non-mergeable revisions. If you check that box, you will only see revisions which you have not yet merged.

So again after you right click and select Merge..., [Show Log], and at the bottom of the log window **check [ ] Hide non-mergeable revisions**.

Additionally, you can further filter your list by adding some filters at the top of the dialog. 
You can also add a filter **-John** to exclude changes made by John. The minus sign indicates a search string to exclude from the list. Or if you want to be sure to exclude changes that belong to change TM1245 you can add the filter **-TM1245**

Answer (score 0):

We spun a service that uses the mergeinfo metadata to create a webpage that displays this information.  So we now setup our "merge paths" in a configuration file (including to trunk) and this service looks for outstanding revisions that have not been merged along the merge paths.

It is VERY useful.